# Get the id of elements dynamically created

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I want to select the elements created dynamically using ajax by id, the code is:

```
$(function(){
   $('#loadFeed').bind('click',function(){ 
        $.getJSON('getData.php', function(json) {
            var output="<ul id='feedsList'>";

            for(var i=json.posts.length-1;i>=json.posts.length-31;i--){
                output+="<li class='post'>";
                output+="<div class='text' id='"+json.posts[i].id+"'>"+json.posts[i].shortmsg+"</div>";         
                output+="</li>";
            }
            output+="</ul>"
            $(output).appendTo('.posts');
    });
  });
});
```

The html codes:

```
<div class="posts">
    <!--dynamic content here-->
</div>
```

I tried to get the id using $(this).attr("id"):

```
$(".post").on("click",".text",function(){
      var this_id =$(this).attr("id");
      alert(this_id);
});
```

But it said undefined. How could I get the id correctly?Thanks!

Comment: Could you see "id" attribute on your page, via Firebug for example?

Comment: have you made sure that `json.posts[i].id` indeed contains something useful?

Comment: @Alexey Yes. There was id attribute containing a number. I can see in Chrome

Comment: May be you could try to use jQuery(".post .text").click(function...?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`$(".post")` should be `$('div.post')`, because you're creating `li` from ajax request with same class. As `div.post` is existing in your DOM and you're appending you  list to it.

That is,

```
$("div.post").on("click","li.post div.text",function(){
      var this_id = this.id;
      alert(this_id);
});
```

Comment: You could make use of the DOM, and use `var this_id = this.id;` which is (marginally) faster, and avoids wrapping `this` needlessly in a jQuery object.

Comment: Actually when I changed to   $(".posts").on("click",".text",function(){
      var this_id =$(this).attr("id");
      alert(this_id);
});                                                                It works! Anyway thx!

Comment: You're absolutely welcome, incidentally, in HTML 5 an `id` is allowed to start with a numeric character. Though there's no indication that the OP is using HTML 5. So it's a worthwhile warning regardless.

Answer (score 2):

Numbers are not valid ids. Ids need to start with letters.

You will need to use something like this:

```
output+="<div class='text' id='post_"+json.posts[i].id+"'>"+json.posts[i].shortmsg+"</div>";
```

Here'se the structure of a valid id: [What are valid values for the id attribute in HTML?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70579/what-are-valid-values-for-the-id-attribute-in-html)